# Python, MySQLdb, unable to update row

Tags: python, mysql-python

I know SO is not a "*debug my code service*" but after checking and retrying for hours either I'm missing something very stupid or maybe there's a bug (or bad compilation) in my MySQLdb module...

Also I've some related question I've put along with the posted code...

```
def NextDocumentIdToCache():
    if not OpenConnection():
        return 0

    # ...setting string values... #

    cur = connection.cursor(mysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM documents WHERE resolutions <> %s AND pdf > 0 AND status = %s AND expire > %s AND locked = %s LIMIT 0,1', (resolutions, status, expireLimit, ''))

    rowsCount = cur.rowcount

    if rowsCount==0:
        return 0

    row = cur.fetchone()

    id = row['document_id']
```

Everything ok since now. Connection opens, I get one row and retrieve the correct **id** that is returned at the end of the function.

Then I need to perform an update operation on the row fetched...

```
    cur.close()

    cur = connection.cursor(mysql.cursors.Cursor)
```

I've closed the cursor and opened a new one. **Do I actually need to do this?** Or can I reuse the same cursor?

```
    cur.execute("""UPDATE documents SET locked = %s WHERE document_id = %s""", ("worker: rendering pages", id))
```

This actually doesn't update the row. No exceptions happens, just don't work.

Finally the function ends...

```
    cur.close()

    return id
```

Also a couple of questions.

What's the difference between

```
cur.execute("""UPDATE documents....
```

and

```
cur.execute("UPDATE documents....
```

I've seen around both versions. What's the functional difference between triple *double-quote*, single *double-quote*, single *single-quote*?

And finally

If I write the query

```
cur.execute("""UPDATE documents SET locked = %s WHERE document_id = %d""", ("worker: rendering pages", id))
```

(note the **%d** instead of **%s**) I get an error. But **id** is a long integer, I've checked. So what's wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The change doesn't take effect:

Are you doing a transaction? You'll need to `commit()` if that's the case. [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), which defines the Python Database API, states that a connection will use transactions even if you have not explicitly enabled them: "Note that if the database supports an auto-commit feature, this must be initially off."

## Quoting

Triple quoted strings are multiline, single quoted strings aren't.

## Interpolation

Because this is not actually string interpolation. Those placeholders are interpreted by MySQLdb, which will handle quoting for you.

Comment: Not explicitly (I didn't wrote code to start a transaction. Just opened the connection and executed the two queries) However adding **connection.commit()** at the end solved the prolem. Thank you.